# Discord.py --> channel.mention

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot for a discord server that simply listens for specific messages, deletes them and then refers the user to a different text channel (in a clickable link by mentioning it)

Here's what I have now:

```
import Discord
import asyncio


client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = '{0.author.mention}\nWrong text channel\nUse '.format(message)
    if message.content.startswith('!p'):
        await client.delete_message(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
    return


client.run('')
```

Ideally, I'd also want to search through a list with `startswith()` instead of just `('!p')` & to ignore all messages from a specific text channel as well but I'm not sure how to do those either

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I've added answers to all of your questions. In the future try posting questions that are different in nature as separate posts. Check out [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Best of luck!

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just add `text_channel = client.get_channel('1234567890')` and reference its mention with `text_channel.mention` (where `1234567890` is the id of the channel you want to link to)

So the code would end up looking something like this

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  text_channel = client.get_channel('1234567890')
  msg = '{0.author.mention}\nWrong text channel\nUse {1.mention}'.format(message,text_channel)
  if message.content.startswith('!p'):
      await client.delete_message(message)
      await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
  return
```

Regarding your second question, you could do something like this

```
  arr = ['!p','!a','!b']
  for a in arr:
    if message.content.startswith(a):
      break
  else:
    return
```

and remove the `if message.content.startswith('!p'):` altogether

To ignore a specific channel just do `if message.channel.id == "9876543210":` at the top of the function (`9876543210` is the id of the channel you want to ignore commands from)
With those changes the code looks like this

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.channel.id == "9876543210":
    return
  arr = ['!p','!a','!b']
  for a in arr:
    if message.content.startswith(a):
      break
  else:
    return
  text_channel = client.get_channel('1234567890')
  msg = '{0.author.mention}\nWrong text channel\nUse {1.mention}'.format(message,text_channel)
  await client.delete_message(message)
  await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
  return
```

Comment: This worked, aside from the bot doesn't recognize any matching message past the second and sometimes only first list index for some reason

Comment: UPDATE: Channel ID is now INT, so remove the ''

Answer (score 13):

Don't know if your problem is solved or not, but for all future developers looking on this thread. A super simple way to get a bot to mention a channel is like this...

```
<#channelID>
```

were the channel ID is the discord ID of the specific channel you wish to mention.

and in an example

```
await message.channel.send("Please go to <#channelID>")
```

I'm honestly a bit confused that no one on this thread has already mentioned this, so I feel like I'm missing something that y'all already know lol.

Comment: You did not miss anything, this works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Log : "+str(client.user))

@client.command()
async def mention(ctx):
    ch = await client.fetch_channel(enter channel id)
    await ctx.send(f"Mention your channel -> {ch}")


client.run("token")
```